# How to stop iOS from showing tomorrow's birthdays everyday

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, notifications

My iPhone, for some reason (I haven't set up anything like that), shows the next day's birthdays everyday at 12:00 (at noon). How do I prevent that? I don't want to remove them from calendar, I just want to remove those annoying notifications.

(Default Alert Times for Birthdays is already set to "None")

Comment: Try turning off the Birthdays calendar in the Calendar app?

Comment: @JohnRamos I *DO* want birthdays in my calendar. I just don't want notifications for them.

Answer (score 1):

- **iOS Calendar:** Go to

  *preferences / mail, contacts & calendar / calendar / default alert times / birthdays*

  and select **none**. That should prevent your iOS calendar from
  notify you whenever there is a birthday in your calendar.
- **Facebook**: Maybe these notifications are from your Facebook app. Try turning these notifications off.

Also have a look at [this (similar) question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79499/how-to-disable-birthday-reminders-in-ios-and-still-view-them-in-the-calendar-app).

Comment: There is an option called "default alert times", and it has the option Birthdays, so it's probably that. **But**, it's already set to none.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu So it did not work? Have you installed another calender app like Fantastical or Sunrise?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work (it was already set to none anyway). No, I don't use any calendar app or import any calendars (other than Facebook).

Comment: Have you tried turning notifications for Facebook of temporarily? I Added that to my initial answer above.

Comment: but I want the calendar reminders for Facebook events

Comment: But you can deactivate notifications for birthdays in your Facebook app without deactivating other notifications. You can do so in the [Facebook app](https://www.facebook.com/help/103859036372845).

Comment: Well, just looked at it, it's already unchecked.